# EclipseLink: createNativeQuery exeption - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

I'm running into a weird issue that hasn't been reported by others from what I could tell, there may be a bug when using createNativeQuery. I have tried so many things to understand why to no avail.

### Current Environment:

- EclipseLink 2.7.3 JPA provider
- PostgreSQL 10.6.1 Database
- Eclipse Photon IDE
- JRE 1.8.0_121

When executing:

```
Long total = (Long) em.createNativeQuery("Project.count").getSingleResult();
```

It's throwing the following:

```
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Project"
  Position: 1
Error Code: 0
Call: Project.count
Query: DataReadQuery(sql="Project.count")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:404)
    at com.bbandt.util.testers.ProjectTester.ProjectVersionMapping(ProjectTester.java:43)
    at com.bbandt.util.testers.ProjectTester.main(ProjectTester.java:21)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Project"
  Position: 1
Error Code: 0
Call: Project.count
Query: DataReadQuery(sql="Project.count")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2096)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeNonCursor(DataReadQuery.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataReadQuery.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.execute(DataReadQuery.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:813)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2981)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1895)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1877)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1842)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:262)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Project"
  Position: 1
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:651)
    ... 21 more
```

Persistence.xml (truncated purposely )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="LocalPostgreSQL" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/Queries.xml</mapping-file>
<!--        <mapping-file>META-INF/ResultsetMappings.xml</mapping-file> 
-->

        <class>com.bbandt.jpa.converters.UUIDAttributeConverter</class>
        <class>model.Component</class>
        <class>model.ComponentVulnerability</class>
        <class>model.ComponentVulnerabilityPK</class>
        <class>model.Project</class>
        <class>model.ProjectVersion</class>
        <class>model.ProjectVersionPK</class>
```

ORM.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">

    <named-native-query name="Project.count">
        <query>Select count(*) as total from public.project</query>
    </named-native-query>

</entity-mappings>
```

From what I could tell, the named native query is not getting resolved back to the actual SQL contents.

Executing this works (and it resolves the ***named-native-query name "Project.count"***):

```
Long total = (Long) em.createNamedQuery("Project.count").getSingleResult();
```

This also works:

```
Long total = (Long) em.createNativeQuery("Select count(*) from project").getSingleResult();
```

I didn't want to resort to JPQL for other reasons unimportant to this thread and I also need to implement SQL Resultset Mappings.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.  I truly ran out of ideas.

Comment: createNamedQuery: Used to define queries with name in mapping file or annotation 
createNativeQuery: Used to execute native/pure SQL queries

Comment: `createNativeQuery("Project.count")` will literally execute the query `Project.count`. `createNativeQuery` doesn't take named queries.

Answer (score 1):

**createNamedQuery**: Used to define queries wthe ith name in mapping file or annotation 
**createNativeQuery**: Used to execute native/pure SQL queries

Since you use createNativeQuery method with a named query you are getting above error

Comment: I understand the difference between the two methods...I was just illustrating that when using createNamedQuery, it actually was able to resolve the named query within the orm.xml  as opposed to createNativeQuery.   Just to prove that it could find "Product.count"

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add...yes, the exception was thrown using the createNamedQuery method using the named-native-query name="Project.count" that's within the orm.xml mapping file.  btw...you can specify a native query within the mapping file too....the only method that will work is when I use createNamedQuery.

Comment: @user10832358  if you are using createNativeQuery method, it won’t identify your named query it accept only native query. Now what is your issue?

Comment: I did not.   So, if you look at the beginning of the thread and what I have within the orm.xml...that does not work.  Referring to createNativeQuery() and specifying the named query in the mapping file.  If I use createNamedQuery() method it will work (but I do not wish to utilize that method since I need to provide additional mappings).   I found a link that's implementing what I am trying to implement (but's it's throwing the stacktrace listed earlier:  https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jpa-named-query-example/ )

Comment: I hope the link I provided explains where native queries can be defined within a mappings files (e.g. orm.xml) and this is what I'm trying to leverage (as opposed to using annotations and a String value within the code).

Comment: You need to be more clear, as your link clearly shows executing named native queries using createNamedQuery and passing in the query 'name' string. This string is used to look up the named query - native or otherwise - from the available definition. If you have issues with named query lookups, state it, otherwise this is 'the' correct answer to the question you posed: createNativeQuery("Project.count") gives 'Project.count' to the database which it cannot understand. If you want to pass in a result set mapping to your native query, that is a completely different issue/question.